# Passing positional argument to Dataproc serverless PySpark script.py

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

I ran the below statement, but it failed to pass an argument (`--args argument="xyz"`) to `script.py`. I tried passing the argument in different ways, but the script fails with an error **`IndexError: list index out of range`**.

Could someone please help? Thanks in advance.

**Command:**

```
gcloud dataproc batches submit pyspark gs://path/script.py \
--project xxx \
--region xxx  \
--batch xxx \
--version 2.1 \
--deps-bucket='xxx' \
--staging-bucket='xxx' \
--service-account xxx  \
--subnet xxx
--args argument="xyz"
```

**Error:**

```
param=sys.argv[1]
               ~~~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 3):

Try something like the following (basically replace `--args` with `--`. Note the space after `--`):

```
gcloud dataproc batches submit pyspark gs://path/script.py \
  --project xxx \
  --region xxx  \
  --batch xxx \
  --version 2.1 \
  --deps-bucket='xxx' \
  --staging-bucket='xxx' \
  --service-account xxx  \
  --subnet xxx \
  -- argument="xyz"
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked and other thing I missed was adding a "\" after the subnet value. gcloud dataproc batches submit pyspark gs://path/script.py
--project xxx \
--region xxx \
--batch xxx \
--version 2.1 \
--deps-bucket='xxx' \
--staging-bucket='xxx' \
--service-account xxx \
--subnet xxx -- \ argument="xyz"